# What will be the time complexity of this code, kindly show me the way?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I was doing an exercise of big-O notation for this piece of code. And I believe that the time complexity will be O(n^2). The code is in python

```
i=0
while i<n:
    while i<n:
        print(i)
        i+=1
```

But. the problem is, the solution showing that the time complexity for this  is O(n)
Is it wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Think about what happens to the outter loop once the inner loop is done.

Comment: The correct answer (strictly speaking) would be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 3):

O(n) is correct. Notice that once the inner loop completes **once**, `i` is no longer less than `n` so the outer loop will also exit.

I will add that in this problem, it is very easy to experiment with the code. Try running it with `n=2` and then `n=4`, you'll notice that when you double `n` in this case, the number of prints is also doubled (which is what you would expect for O(n)). If this were O(n^2), you would expect 4 times as many printed lines when `n` is doubled.

Comment: Not quite. Strictly speaking, `O(n log n)` would be the correct answer since converting `i` to a string takes `O(log i)` time.

Comment: I got it now Kraigolas, if i=0 it will enter in the while loop and then inside the nested while loop but it will not come outside of that nested while loop till i is greater than N. So the nested while loop run for n times, and only compiler comes outside of nested while loop when i is greater than N. So it will not run the outer while loop more than on and come out of the loop.
So, the time complexity will be 1+1+n ->O(n)
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

1. At the beginning, `i = 0`;
2. the first `while` loop begins;
3. the second `while` loop begins;
4. for `n` iterations, `i` has been increased;
5. when `i = n`, the second while loop ends;
6. immediately after, the first `while` loop ends since `i = n`.

So, the program performed only one iteration of the first `while` loop, and in this iteration, the second `while` loop performed n iterations -> `O(n)`.